# C# .NET RichTextBox GetCharOffsetFromPosition?

Tags: c#, .net, string, richtextbox, superscript

Is there a way to get character offset from a position?

I have a box that looks like this -

[image: Polynomial in a richtextbox]

I want to parse it **character by character** but I want to detect when it is *superscript* (which I achieved by setting **SelectionCharOffset** to **10**

What I have is a loop that looks like this so I can acces the position with *i*

```
for (int i = 0; i < Text1.TextLength; i++) {
     //I can use things here like Text1.Text[i]...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you achieved superscript.

Use the SelectionCharOffset property (along with `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` to select one character at a time) and see if its a positive number (since positive represents superscript and negative represents subscript).

```
for (int i = 0; i < Text1.TextLength; i++)
{
    Text1.SelectionStart = i;
    Text1.SelectionLength = 1;

    if (Text1.SelectionCharOffset > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```